# SOLVED Datagridview Reload after Button click using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I got a datagridview and per Button I can Add items, and now I want to see in the datagridview that something changed.

I tried so many thing. `this.Refresh(); this.Invalidate();` nothing works,

I found `Application.Restart();` but I am not happy with this solution.
Is there anything else??

```
var contex = new frachtkostenEntities();
try
{
    var x = new Kunden()
    {
        Kundenname = first,
        Zielort = second,
    };

    contex.Kunden.Add(x);
    contex.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now the new Items are in the Database, but the datagridview stays the same

This is the code to display the database

```
frachtkostenEntities context = new frachtkostenEntities();
var item = from p in context.Artikel
            select new
            {
                Artikelnummer = p.Artikelnummer,
                Bezeichnung = p.Bezeichnung,
            };
dgvDisplayDataBase.DataSource = item.ToList();
```

Comment: Welcome! If you can share some of your code that would be helpful. You don't even have to share a picture but you can copy/paste the code and then format it as code in the editor.

Comment: var contex = new frachtkostenEntities();
            try
            {
                var x = new Kunden()
                {
                    Kundenname = first,
                    Zielort = second,
                };

Comment: contex.Kunden.Add(x); 
                    contex.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that new data has not been uploaded, you can create a function

```
void LoadData()
{
    //code load data from db
}
```

Then add code to the event AddButton

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code add new record
    LoadData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to refresh, reload or invalidate when setup properly as per below.

To see immediate change when adding a new item is to setup with a BindingList and a BindingSource. Then add the new item to the BindingList.

Also consider using INotifyPropertyChanged for when a property value changes in the model.

Using the following model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using North.Interfaces;

namespace North.Models
{
    public partial class Contacts : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _firstName;
        private string _lastName;
        private int? _contactTypeIdentifier;

        public int Id => ContactId;
        public int ContactId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get => _firstName;
            set
            {
                _firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get => _lastName;
            set
            {
                _lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int? ContactTypeIdentifier
        {
            get => _contactTypeIdentifier;
            set
            {
                _contactTypeIdentifier = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        
    }
}
```

Then in the form, load data to the BindingList, add button adds a new record and shows the new primary key.

```
namespace North.Forms
{
    public partial class ContactAddForm : Form
    {
        
        private BindingList<Contacts> _bindingList;
        private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        
        public ContactAddForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            Shown += OnShown;
        }

        private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var context = new NorthwindContext())
            {
                _bindingList = new BindingList<Contacts>(context.Contacts.ToList());

                _bindingSource.DataSource = _bindingList;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;
            }
            
            _bindingSource.MoveLast();

        }

        private void AddNewContactButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // hard coded contact
            var newContact = new Contacts()
            {
                FirstName = "Karen", 
                LastName = "Payne", 
                ContactTypeIdentifier = 1
            };
            
            // add to list and display in DataGridView
            _bindingList.Add(newContact);

            // save changes
            using (var context = new NorthwindContext())
            {
                context.Add(newContact).State = EntityState.Added;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // See new primary key
            MessageBox.Show("Id " + newContact.ContactId.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

To see values of the current row in the DataGridView

```
private void CurrentContactButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Contacts current = _bindingList[_bindingSource.Position];
    MessageBox.Show($"{current.ContactId}, {current.FirstName}, {current.LastName}");
}
```